# Android Studio Hangs every few RUNs

Tags: android, android-studio, freeze

My android studio freezes every 3-4 RUN's no error dialog, nothing.Program just completely hangs. Tried to look for a fix but found nothing related to no error pop up HANG. I'm using my phone to test my app when AS hangs the app gets runs and gets installed though. my android studio version is 1.3 build tools 21.1.2 compile sdk API 22
Any help I get is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I have the same. The most annoying in this, that due to this, I'm loosing part of work. (Only closing AS by Task Manager and opening it again is making it again working, but part of work done is lost) (Issue is also appearing on 1.3.1)

Comment: Ditto - though mine is on OSX (Yosemite). I also upgraded to 1.4 Preview 2 and then 3. Still the same problem. Doesn't seem specific to any particular UI action, but if I do something like open a file, or RUN, or ... then it will spin the wait wheel.